# Copy the files from Linux vm to azure repository

Tags: bash, azure

I don't know if it's possible or not.

I have one Linux vm where we have some files. we don't have any git installed inside the Linux vm, in other hand we have azure repository.

Using azure pipeline job, we have copy all the files from Linux vm to azure repository and start the build, if the build is successful then we have to merge the copied code into azure repo.

Please let me if it's possible

Comment: This is about Azure DevOps or something else? I haven't tried something like this, but if this is Azure DevOps, wouldn't pipeline artifact work for the files?

Comment: It's azure devops only kindly help me

Comment: Well then how about pipeline artifacts? Have you tried something? Why didn't it work?